# Team Explorer Everywhere - Domain user could not be validated

Tags: macos, tfs, terminal, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using Team Explorer Everywhere command line tool on a mac. I've setup a connection to the TFS and i got my files. Checked them out for editing and i see on another machine they are indeed checked out. Now when i try to check them back in i run

```
sudo tf checkin MiniOrka.iOS -recursive -comment:Testing -login:myUsernam@myDomain,myPW
```

But all i get is:

> Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault: >RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated. ---> >RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated. ---> >RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated.
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAP12Service.examineResponseDOMForFault(SOAP12Service.java:127)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:826)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:454)
>       at ms.tfs.workitemtracking.clientservices._03._ClientService2Soap12Service.getMetadataEx2(_ClientService2Soap12Service.java:745)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.update(Metadata.java:515)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.update(Metadata.java:482)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WITContext.(WITContext.java:97)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.getContext(WorkItemClient.java:359)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.WorkItemClient.query(WorkItemClient.java:521)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.commands.CommandCheckin.checkWorkItems(CommandCheckin.java:354)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.commands.CommandCheckin.run(CommandCheckin.java:181)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.Application.run(Application.java:294)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.Application.run(Application.java:144)
>       at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.Main.main(Main.java:33)

And my files remain checked out. I am a member of the Contributor group (they can add, modify and delete items within the team project).

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: And it's definetly not my login or domain info. If i pass the wrong login info(username, domain, password) i get a different message.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-login:myUsernam@myDomain` and entering the password at the prompt that follows.

Comment: Well i did that. I said so in the question. Also if I input a wrong username or password I get a different message as I commented. So i don't think it's the problem.